# play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**MODEL.USER**

When I am working on Play 2.3.x, I want to use JPA to implement login function. Then I got this error. It seems the authenticate has successfully receive the args from controller.

```
public static  User authenticate(String email, String password){

        String hql = "from User u where u.email= ? and u.password= ?";
        Query query = JPA.em().createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter(0, email);
        query.setParameter(1, password);
        User user = (User) query.getResultList();

        return user;
}
```

**Controller.User**

```
public static class Login{

    public String email;
    public String password;

    public String validate(){
        LOG.info("validating user");
        User user = User.authenticate(email, password);

        if(user == null){
            return "Invalid email or password";
        }
        LOG.info("validated Customer:"+user.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full stacktrace. The error logging in Play Framework could definitely be improved here (feel free to raise an issue). In the meantime, you could get the error by catching and printing out `RuntimeException`s in your code.

Comment: Are you missing @Transactional annotation?